# Comparing counts in a SQL where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: users and photos.

Users have many photos. Photos have a column called user_id, photos have one user. Photos also have a column called reported which is 0 or 1.

I need to know the number of users who have at least 1 photo with reported = 1. I also need to get the number of users who have at least 2 photos with reported = 1.

How would I do this? Here's what I'd like to do, but it obviously doesn't work:

```
select count(*)
from users join 
 (select * from photos where photos.reported = 1) as p2 
 on users.photo_id = p2.id;
```

Comment: Check out the HAVING clause, it may be what you need: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: Do you really have users.photo_id field? That means that you have to have as many entries in the user table as there are photos. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: What is your expected result look like?  I just can't visualize the end result... given the above.

Comment: sorry @PawelVeselov, I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get a histogram of the counts:

```
select numreported, count(*), min(user_id), max(user_id)
from (select p.user_id, sum(p.reported = 1) as numreported
      from photos p
      group by p.user_id
     ) p
group by numreported
order by numreported;
```

This gives you the number of users that have all counts of `numreported`, including 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is at least 1

```
select count(distinct userid)
from photos
where reported = 1
```

This is at least 2.

```
select count(distinct userid)
from photos
where reported = 1
group by userid
having count(userid) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the  following should  work

```
 select count(hasOne) cntHasOne, count(hasTwo) cntHasTwo from
(select users.user_id, 1  hasOne,
case when count(*) > 1 then  1 else 0 end hasTwo
from users inner join solution on(users.user_id = solution.user_id) 
where solution.winning_status  = 1
group by user_id) T1
```